# How I can join two or more object in C#?

Tags: c#, object, join

I want to validate a set of object and I need to make them together.

```
var mensajesDeValidacion = _validador.Valida();
if (!_validador.EsValido){
throw new ValidacionException("Corrija los siguientes errores", mensajesDeValidacion);}

public class Empresa : IEmpresa
{
  public int IdEmpresa{get;set;}
  public string Nombre{get;set;}
}

public interface IEmpresa
{
  int IdEmpresa{get;set;}
  string Nombre{get;set;}
}
```

and other class

```
public class ContactoEmpresa : IContactoEmpresaEmpresa
{
  public int IdContactoEmpresaEmpresa{get;set;}
  public string Direccion{get;set;}
}

public interface IContactoEmpresaEmpresa
{
  int IdContactoEmpresaEmpresa{get;set;}
  string Direccion{get;set;}
}
```

How i can join this two object or more?

Comment: What do you mean be *join* the objects!?

Comment: What about making a third class that implements IEmpresa & IContactoEmprestEmpresa?

Answer (score 1):

create new class with fields `IEmpresa` and `IContactoEmpresaEmpresa`
or use `Tuple<T1,T2>`

Comment: how ? 
class some {
  public IEmpresa Empresa{get;set;}
  public IContactoEmpresa Empresa {get;set;}
}

Answer (score 0):

Tupples where introduced not long ago, you can take a look, its easy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx